# What is the scope of the template reference variable in Angular?

Tags: angular, templates, variables, scope

What is the scope of the template reference variable in Angular?

I can not find a clear answer to my question in documentation. Even though empirically I can say that the whole template can access the template reference variable.

**1** Is it the case? Is the template reference variable guaranteed to be accessible in the whole template?

**2** Or is the template reference variable accessible only in the child and sibling elements of the element which is referenced by the template reference variable?

Over [here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#key-event-filtering-with-keyenter) I found the following statement:

> Use template variables to refer to elements — The `newHero` template variable refers to the `<input>` element. You can reference `newHero` from any sibling or child of the `<input>` element.

Does it mean that only the **2** is guaranteed by Angular?

Comment: You can refer anywhere in the component's template... else if you declare inside a *ngFor. In this case, the variable is used only inside the *ngFor. - In ts you can get all the elements with this template using `@ViewChildren`-

Comment: @Eliseo, could you, please, provide a source where you have learned about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Template reference variable could be accessed from anywhere in the template *as long as the corresponding element is present in the DOM*.

For eg. you cannot access a template ref variable inside an `<ng-template>` element if it is not yet rendered.

```html
<ng-template #templateOne let-message let-showAdditional="show">
  <div #templateDiv>
    One <br />
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-container *ngIf="templateDiv">
  Got template div
</ng-container>
```

Here Angular will throw an error

> Property 'templateDiv' does not exist on type 'SomeComponent'.

because the element that is referenced by the variable is not present in the DOM.

---

Regarding your point 2.

> You can reference `newHero` from any sibling or child of the 
>   element.

They were referring to the specific tutorial. Notice it didn't say

> You can reference `newHero` <strike>***only***</strike> from any sibling or child of the 
>   element.

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var):

> You can refer to a template reference variable anywhere in the
>   component's template.